# Proof involving Induction

Tags: proof-writing

Prove that for every integer n ≥ 1, we have

$$
\sum_{i=1}^ni^3=\left(\frac{n(n+1)}2\right)^2
$$

Solve using Mathematical Induction, include the Inductive Step

Base Case is that both the left and right side $=1$ when $n=1$. 
and the Inductive Hypothesis is $1^3+2^3+\dots +k^3=\frac{\left( k(k+1)\right)^2}2$

Comment: What is your base case? What is your hypothesis?

Comment: Always indicate what you have tried, what you know, etc.

Comment: Base Case is that both the left and right side =1 when n=1. and the Inductive Hypothesis is 1^3+2^3+…k^3=(k(k+1))^2/2

Answer (score 2):

Define
$$
A_n = \frac{n^2(n+1)^2}4
$$
then what is $A_n - A_{n-1}$?